# How to know the request to fuse is congested

Tags: fuse

I am new to fuse. I have 2 questions:

1. Can I only set the value of `congestion_threshold` itself without changing default `max_background`?
2. If the number of number of asynchronous requests in the pending and processing queues reaches the value of the tunable congestion threshold parameter, how can I know it is congested? Where to check the logging? dmesg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without testing*, looking at the source code there seems to be such a separate option: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/lib/helper.c#L90:

```java
    CONN_OPTION("congestion_threshold=%u", congestion_threshold, 0),
    CONN_OPTION("congestion_threshold=", set_congestion_threshold, 1),
```

Also from the code, looks like you can configure it using `fuse_parse_conn_info_opts`. See https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/include/fuse_common.h#L523:

```java
 * The following options are recognized:
 *
...
 *   -o max_background=N    sets conn->max_background
 *   -o congestion_threshold=N  sets conn->congestion_threshold
...
 **/
struct fuse_conn_info_opts* fuse_parse_conn_info_opts(struct fuse_args *args);
```

Looking in the Kernel code, no prints for the actual congestion happening.

Comment: Thanks very much. I took a look at fuse 2.9, it has such configuration: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/fuse_2_9_bugfix/lib/fuse_lowlevel.c#L1864-L1869 not sure why.

Comment: Looking at git blame https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/commit/8b2a7f59b3d07fb82f7df8fa8efd7ff38700e60d it was written by Miklos 10 years ago. Suggest you ask him in the libfuse mailing list